# Hosting MariaDB on Azure as an app service

Tags: azure, mariadb

Is it possible to host MariaDB as an average app service on Azure?

I would just like to install and maintain MariaDB similar as a web app on Azure App Service using the same pricing conditions as for it.

I am aware that there is a SAAS service "Azure Database for MariaDB" available, but I am not interested in that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to host a MariaDB on an app service in Azure.

If you do not want to go with "Azure Database for MariaDB", you could go rent a VM and manage it yourself. However, that would be the same thing as going with "Azure Database for MariaDB", just a little cheaper :)